# What are easy steps of finding cutpoint in continuous variable with Time to event outcome, in Stata?

Tags: regression, stata, cox-model, decision-theory, binning

I find it painful to manually guess a dichotomized cutpoint predictor (continuous) for an time to event outcome in Simple Cox proportional hazard model.

Currently I was trying to find the cutpoint that make the smallest p-value in the model.

If I can find it, Do I have to use ROC curve to fine-tune it? if so, how to do it?

Comment: Don't dichotomize a continuous variable. In addition, looking for a data manipulation to minimize your p-values is data dredging.

Comment: See [this page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable/68839#68839) and many others on this site why you should not try to break up your continuous predictor this way, for this or for any type of regression/classification scheme. Much better to learn about the actual relation between your continuous predictor and outcome when standard clinical variables are taken into account in your Cox model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my case, the cut-point is needed to find the proper criteria to make a diagnosis of a particular disease.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Don't dichotomize a continuous variable. In addition, looking for a data manipulation to minimize your p-values is data dredging. – gung

See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable/68839#68839) and many others on this site why you should not try to break up your continuous predictor this way, for this or for any type of regression/classification scheme. Much better to learn about the actual relation between your continuous predictor and outcome when standard clinical variables are taken into account in your Cox model. – EdM

To which OP responded:  *In my case, the cut-point is needed to find the proper criteria to make a diagnosis of a particular disease*.  **Answer to that is**: If the goal is to find a decision cut-point to make diagnosis for a particular disease, then do that **after model construction and estimation**, estimation and decision is different problems. In particular, decision tresholds could vary with patient caracteristics.  See for instance the F Harrell quote in [Calculating F-Score, which is the "positive" class, the majority or minority class?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191645/calculating-f-score-which-is-the-positive-class-the-majority-or-minority-cla/192765#192765)